# jQuery - Controlling div visibility with a Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Updated: I would like to control the visibility of the bottom divs based on the value of the top SELECT..

i.e

```
selected = dogs:: only bulldog, pitbull visible
selected = fish:: GOLDFISH! visible
```

etc..

Appreciate it.. Sorry I didn't do a better job of explaining my question initially -

```
<select>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
  <option value="fish">fish</option>
</select>

<div id="dog">bulldog</div>
<div id="cat">stray cat</div>
<div id="dog">pitbull</div>
<div id="cat">alley cat</div>
<div id="fish">GOLDFISH!</div>
```

Comment: If the divs were all in some kind of container this would be a bit easier with jQuery selectors. Is there a container around them?

Comment: You have invalid HTML.  Element ids must be unique.  They can't all have `id="petinfo"`.  But, they can all have `class="petinfo [dog|cat|fish]"`.

Comment: HTML Corrected; Still can't seem to find the way to get it done - apologies for the poor HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectionChanged(){
HideAll();
var selected=$('#pets option:selected').text();
var selectString='.';
selectString+=selected;
$(selectString).show();
};
function HideAll(){
$('.dog').hide();
$('.cat').hide();
$('.fish').hide();
};
</script>

<select id="pets" onchange="selectionChanged()">
    <option>dog</option>
    <option>cat</option>
    <option>fish</option>
  </select>

<div id=somepets>
  <div class="dog">bulldog</div>
  <div class="cat">stray cat</div>
  <div class="dog">pitbull</div>
  <div class="cat">alley cat</div>
  <div class="fish">GOLDFISH!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The onchange event is not going to fire on a div.

Comment: Good catch, I moved it to the select where it belongs :)

Comment: Appreciate it Joshua.. How could the function only show the DIVS which match the value of the SELECT.. I updated the question to better reflect what I'm looking to accomplish.. Appreciate you Answer and time spent -

Comment: $('#'+$('#pets option:selected').text).show();  this should do just that.  what is happening here is the inner selector is getting the text of the selected option (i.e. dog, cat).  This value is then added to the string in the outer selector, which will now either look like $('#dog') or $('#cat').  It then calls .show() on the selected elements.  Calling HideAll() first will hide ALL of the divs so only the ones you tell to show() after will be shown.

Comment: The event is firing but my console echos.. Error: regular expression too complex
Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
Line: 71

Comment: Love the simplicity just having some trouble making it work -

Comment: ok well lets stuff the result of the inner selector into a variable:  
var selectedOption=$('#pets option:selected').text();
var selectorString='#'+selectedOption;
$(selectorString).show();

Comment: have a look.. http://jsfiddle.net/pschramm/ePgjG/ it fires and hides / shows divs.. but it doesn't seem to relate to my selection..  just to clarify.. my goal is to select DOG and 'hide' the other divs

Comment: correct HideAll() is hiding ALL of the divs, then the other stuff is getting the text from the selected option in the dropdown and showing the appropriate divs.

Comment: really appreciate your help and sorry if i'm overlooking something obvious.. have the code running here.. http://jsfiddle.net/pschramm/ePgjG/  -- regardless of the the SELECT=dog it shows alley cat and pitbull..   correct behavior would be SELECT=DOG all DIV=DOG would be visible.. others invisible.. Am I taking the wrong approach all together?

Comment: I edited/formatted/debugged it for you.  This worked in chrome and IE for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#pets').change(function() {
    $('#somepets div').hide();
    $('#somepets div.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

But for this you should change your class names to match the values of the options. Also you need to give your "select" element an ID.

EDIT: To clarify a bit, this selector is going to try and find the select element by its ID "pets" so you need to add id="pets". The name and ID can be the same value.

EDIT: Since you're having some trouble with the HTML here is what it would need to look like to work with my method.

```
<select id="pets">
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
  <option value="fish">fish</option>
</select>

<div id="somepets">
  <div class="dog">bulldog</div>
  <div class="cat">stray cat</div>
  <div class="dog">pitbull</div>
  <div class="cat">alley cat</div>
  <div class="fish">GOLDFISH!</div>
</div>
```